# Commentbox instead of text box?

Tags: asp.net

I want the user to be able to leave comments, a few sentences perhaps. TextBox is to no use, but I see no asp:CommentBox

Any advice on what to use instead?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set property TextMode to MultiLine

As this

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Text1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" />
```

You can see more on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textmode.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If the comments part of your project is so important i suggest using third-parties for these such functions

check these 2 sites

[Disqus](http://disqus.com/) Elevating the discussion, anywhere on the web.

[livefyre](http://www.livefyre.com/) WE MAKE YOUR SITE SOCIAL.

i know that's not answer to your question, but i think you should at least know they are exist.